# Reg: aggregate function using group by format the output

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

We are using below query:

```
 db.logins.aggregate([ 
 { $match:{"$and":  [{"agentRole": {"$in": ["ds_se_t","se_bt_tec","ne_bs_tec","fe_bs_tec"]}},
 {"loginLogoutTime": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-10-25T00:00:00.000"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-10-25T20:00:00.000-0400")}}]}}, 
 { $group: {_id: {Dates: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime" }} } ,
 uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$Uid"}, User: {$addToSet: "$Uid"} }}, 
 { $project: {  "_id" : NumberInt(0),   "Dates" : "$_id.Dates", "TOTALUSERS" : {$size:"$uniqueCount"}, "Uid" : "$User" }}

 ])
```

Output is showing like:

```
{
    "Dates" : "2020-10-25",
    "TOTALUSERS" : 7,
    "Uid" : [ 
        "ab179", 
        "ca973", 
        "dg1212", 
        "pb9317", 
        "fc9875", 
        "bs1967", 
        "de1987", 
 
    ]
}
```

But we need the output in format:

Dates and Uid in single rows how can we format the above query, thanks in advance.

We need the output in row wise  like below:

```
Dates   TOTALUSERS  Uid

10/25/2020  7      ab179
10/25/2020  7      ca973
10/25/2020  7      dg1212
10/25/2020  7      pb9317
10/25/2020  7      fc9875
10/25/2020  7      bs1967
10/25/2020  7      de1987
```

Please suggest how can we achieve this result.

Comment: Can you post the expected output ?

Comment: Thanks Tiya Jose, added the expected output, can pls suggest.

Comment: @singh_dba expected output is not even valid json. what do you mean? The only option I feel close is to export that as csv, though I'm not sure what's the output.

Comment: HI Minsky, i have added my expected output kindly suggest.